# axios post request with headers and body are not working

Tags: javascript, axios

In my project, I use this modified axios function to make an API request:

```
// api.js
function request (method, path, { query, params }, fields) {
  query = escapeQuery(query); // make query string
  return axios[method](`${API.URL}${path}?${query}`, {
    ...fields,
    params
  });
}

let methods = {};
['post', 'get', 'patch', 'delete', 'put'].forEach(method => {
  methods[method] = (...args) => request(method, ...args);
});
```

So in actual case, like this:

```
import API from 'api.js';
...
getSomePages (state) {
  var config = {
    headers: { 'x-access-token': state.token }
  };
  let query = { 'page': state.selected_page };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    API.get(`/myapipath`, {query}, config).then(...);
  });
},
...
```

When I call `API.get()` like the above, it works very well. The problem is when I call `API.post`. It seems that it cannot distinguish the correct field. For example, when I call:

```
likePost (state, post_id, user_id) {
  var config = {
    headers: {
      'x-access-token': state.token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  };
  var data = {
    post_id, user_id
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    API.post(`/myapipath`, {data}, config).then(...);
  });
},
```

This `API.post` call keeps failing, so I looked up the request and found that it doesn't have headers - all the fields I've sent are in the request body.

So I tried something like:

```
API.post(`/myapipath`, {}, config, data)...
API.post(`/myapipath`, data, config)...
API.post(`/myapipath`, {data, config})...
etc...
```

but it all failed. It looks like they all cannot understand which is the header. How can I solve this?

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config, `axios.get` accepts 2 parameters while `axios.post` accepts 3. And in your `request` method, it always passes 2 parameters. Maybe that's why `config` cannot pass into `axios.post` function.

Comment: thanks @shaunshia i changed `request` method and it worked.